# I need to make a realistic mercury liquid simulation

Tags: animation, physics, mantaflow

I'm trying to achieve this liquid appearance:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0oTy8k7bF8

But I got this:

https://youtu.be/n2H6NsxAiF0

As you can see, my liquid is disjoining on small balls.
Which parameter could I modify to get the first video liquid appearance?
Thank you.

Comment: It would help to know what you have tried.  Can you share screenshots of your material nodes and other settings, or better, share your blend file?  (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: maybe play with the Particle Radius or Sampling (I don't remember which one) of your domain?